# How to convert string to integer using stoi()?

Tags: c++, arrays, string

> If there are more than 3 letters together (i.e. next to each other) from the given Alphabet Set: {a,g,w,k,l}, then your string is “BAD”. If a number is repeated more than three times, then your string is “BAD”. Print "1” if string is GOOD, else print "0".

For the first condition, I am able to do it. But for the second condition, I am having problem with converting a string to an int. I tried using `stoi()` but I think I am not using it correctly.

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {

  int t;
  cin >> t;
  while (t--> 0) {
    string s;
    cin >> s;
    int ccount = 0;

    int arr[10] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
    bool b = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < s.size(); i++) {
      if (s[i] == 'a' || s[i] == 'g' || s[i] == 'w' || s[i] == 'k' || s[i] == 'l') {
        ccount++;
        if (ccount >= 3) {
          b = false;
          break;
        }
      } else if (isdigit(s[i])) {
        ccount = 0;
        int num = stoi( & s, sizeof(s) * i, 10);
        arr[num]++;
        int k = 0;
        for (k = 0; k < 10; k++) {
          if (arr[k] >= 3) {
            b = false;
            break;
          }
        }
      } else {
        ccount = 0;
      }

    }
    if (b == true) {
      cout << 1 << endl;
    } else {
      cout << 0 << endl;
    }

  }
  return 0;
}
```

Input:

```
3
qw2uha
awkl5
y2y2y2y2
```

Output:

```
1
0
0
```

**EDIT**: ASCII conversion works very well.

I have a not so important problem, I know we can't directly compare integers of different signedness, but still I am curious.

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {

  int t;
  cin >> t;
  while (t--> 0) {
    string s;
    cin >> s;
    int ccount = 0;
    int arr[10] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
    bool b = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < s.size(); i++) {
      if (s[i] == 'a' || s[i] == 'g' || s[i] == 'w' || s[i] == 'k' || s[i] == 'l') {
        ccount++;
        if (ccount >= 3) {
          b = false;
          break;
        }
      } else if (isdigit(s[i])) {
        ccount = 0;
        int num = s[i] - '0';
        arr[num]++;
        int k = 0;
        for (k = 0; k < 10; k++) {
          if (arr[k] > 3) {
            b = false;
            break;
          }
        }
      } else {
        ccount = 0;
      }
    }
    if (b == true) {
      cout << 1 << endl;
    } else {
      cout << 0 << endl;
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

I am getting this warning :

```
14:23: warning: comparison of integer expressions of different signedness: 'int' and 'std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>::size_type' {aka 'unsigned int'} [-Wsign-compare]
   14 |     for (int i = 0; i < s.size(); i++) {
      |                     ~~^~~~~~~~~~
]
```

Is there any way to fix the warning?

Comment: `stoi` doesn't do what you think it does. It attempts to convert an ***entire*** string to an integer, while this task obviously refers to a ***single*** digit 0 through 9. All you have to do is do exactly the same identical thing you're doing for letters, but just for characters '0' through '9'. This doesn't appear to have anything to do, whatsoever, with `stoi`.

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i < s.size(); i++) {` - try changing from `int` to `size_t` (logically, you'd want to use `std::string::size_type` to match the return type of `s.size()`, but that's a lot to type, and `size_t` is guaranteed to work, and bother are `unsigned`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert a single ASCII character representing a digit like this:

```
int num = s[i] - '0';
```

That works because inside the string, each character is represented by an ASCII code - they're listed in the table below.  The character `'0'` has ASCII code 48 decimal and other digits increment from there.  When you do `s[i] - '0'` and say `s[i]` is `'5'`, it calculates 53 - 48 = 5.
`
[image]

---

[`std::stoi()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) is only useful if you have a `string` starting with (optional whitespace) then a number, e.g. `"1x"` (`stoi` would extract the number 1), `"  123"` (123), or `"44kx2"` (44).  As your `s` string may have characters before or afterwards, you could use [`s.substr(i, 1)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr) to extract the single digit as a `string`, then use `std::stoi()` on that, but the ASCII conversion above is faster/ simpler/ more-direct.

Comment: It's also not necessary to do any ASCII conversion at all, since you can just do direct character comparison to `'0'` through `'9'` or use `std::isdigit`.

Comment: @NathanPierson: I'm not sure what your point is.  The code is already using `isdigit`, and I haven't suggested changing that - I've just supplied a new calculation for `num`.  Discussion of ASCII is just so OP can see that in the ASCII representation of digits, they have incrementing values such that the calculation will work.

Comment: Oh, yes, I see now.